# Arduino nano (clone) with ethernet shield only works when I open up serial monitor

Tags: serial, arduino-nano, ethernet

```cpp
#include <EtherCard.h>

static byte mymac[] = { 0x7A,0x69,0x69,0x2D,0x30,0x31 };

byte Ethernet::buffer[500];
static uint32_t timer;

const char website[] PROGMEM = "x0201g2.cloudapp.net";

static void my_callback (byte status, word off, word len) {
  delay(1000);
}

void setup () {

  Serial.begin(57600);
  ether.begin(sizeof Ethernet::buffer, mymac, 10);

  ether.dhcpSetup();

  ether.dnsLookup(website);
}

void loop () {

  ether.packetLoop(ether.packetReceive());

  if (millis() > timer) {
    timer = millis() + 5000;
    ether.browseUrl(PSTR("/foo/"), "bar", website, my_callback);
  }
}
```

The way I tested this is I open up SSH terminal for `x0201g2.cloudapp.net` to monitor any incoming traffic.

The result is that it works fine, when I have the "serial monitor" (in Arduino IDE) open. I would see that there's a consistent stream of `GET` requests.

However, when I do not have the serial monitor open nothing ever happen.

Initially I had some `Serial` println to show response status and IP address, so I thought it might be related to the fact that the MCU's serial  controller is waiting for a handshake or some sort of ACK/NACK to happen...if that make sense.

However, that was not the case now because even after I have removed all serial print statements it is behaving in exactly the same way (except that my monitor will show up blank, but I still need to bring it up for it to work).

Comment: Also, without `Serial.begin()` nothing will work as well.

Comment: Could it be related to voltage level differences (Nano = 5V) and ENC28J60 wants 3.3V - this particular ethernet board doesn't seem to have a level shifter on it. But if that's true, nothing should work regardless of whether i have serial monitor open or not.. right?

Comment: Maybe it's because it's some unknown cheap clone? You should try it with a genuine one.

Comment: Look at the ATmega reset pin.

Comment: @ChrisStratton could you give more hint? Are you saying it might be because of auto reset?

Comment: Update: Tried this with Genuine Arduino Nano. Still same behavior.

Comment: @ChrisStratton could it be something to do with voltage differences at RESET pin? Could you elaborate. Thanks in advance.